# Index out of range exception unhandled and not sure why

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

```
 Dim times() As String
    For i = 0 To events.GetLength(1)
        ReDim Preserve times(i + 1)
        SQLQuery("Select event_entry.Time from event, event_entry, swimmer, users where event_entry.eventID = event.EventID and event_entry.SwimmerID = swimmer.SwimmerID and users.userid = swimmer.userid and users.username = '" & CurrentUser & "' and event.stroke = '" & events(0, Math.Max(0, i - 1)) & "' and event.Distance = '" & events(1, Math.Max(0, i - 1)) & "' order by event_entry.time asc limit 1")
        While reader.Read()
            **times(i) = reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString**
        End While
        reader.Close()
    Next
```

This keeps throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException on the highlighted line and I am not sure why. I have done a similar thing previously and it worked just fine. 
As you can see I have declared times as an undefined array and then changed it size to fit. 
The exception is thrown on the first iteration through. Any help would be much appreciated

The code below is where I have done a similar thing and it works perfectly. The code also shows what reader is and how it is declared and used.

```
While reader.Read
        ReDim Preserve events(1, count)
        events(0, count) = reader.GetString(0)
        events(1, count) = reader.GetInt16(1)
        count += 1
    End While

Public connection As New MySqlConnection("server=*****; user id=root; password=*****; database=******; Convert Zero DateTime = True")
Public CurrentUser As String
Public command As New MySqlCommand
Public Poisition As String
Public reader As MySqlDataReader

Sub SQLQuery(ByVal stm As String)
    command.CommandText = stm
    reader = command.ExecuteReader
End Sub
```

Update:
It only seems to be a problem when retrieving data from a DATETIME column. Does anyone know why???

Comment: you arent resizing it in the while loop; a List(of String) would obviate the whole problem and question

Comment: Dim times As List(Of String)
        For i = 0 To events.GetLength(1)
            SQLQuery("........")
            While reader.Read()
                times.Add(reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString)
            End While
            reader.Close()
        Next                                                                                                              Is this what you are suggesting, because it still comes up with the same error

Comment: Maybe `reader.GetDateTime(0)` is where the problem is. You showed us nothing about `reader`, so it is not possible to be sure.

Comment: @ACoder The code in your comment should have started with `Dim times As New List(Of String)`, i.e. with a `New`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks I have added that in but it is still not working I have included above what reader is and how it is used.

Comment: what is the datatype of `event_entry.Time`?